# Making jackson ObjectMapper serialize doubles with 4 digits past decimal point

Tags: jackson

I have an Object something like this:

```
class Foo{
    double bar = 3.325256332;
}
```

If I serialize this using the default jackson ObjectMapper I get all of the decimal points after the decimal point.  I know I can specify that the class or the member variable is to be serialized in a specific way using an annotation, but what I really want is a way to modify my ObjectMapper that is doing the serialization so that as I add member variables to the Foo class, or use the ObjectMapper to serialize other classes I don't have to remember to modify the other classes / members to have a special serializer.

Ideally I am looking for something vaguely like the following, even though this doesn't actually exist:

```
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
m.setPrecision(4);
```

This way I can know that anything I did with this ObjectMapper will come up with 4 decimal places.

Comment: <s>Could you add something like this to your ObjectMapper MAPPER.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(BigDecimal.class, new MyJsonFormatVisitorWrapper()) where MyJsonFormatVisitorWrapper did the truncating to 4 decimal places? Haven't tried it , just a suggestion</s> Sorry, think that's just for serialisation. Could you use something like `MAPPER.addHandler(new MyDeserializationProblemHandler())`